# What is the permissions difference in Windows XP/7/8 between a local admin user and a domain user in the local Administrators group?

Tags: windows-7, permissions

There are a few questions that are similar here, but I'm inspired to dig a little more deeply into the internals of how applications check for administrative privileges and how they can be affected by the properties of the logged in user.

**The problem**:

I have a Canon network printer driver (http://www.usa.canon.com/nw3s/CanonUSA/DownloadContents/English/0100386001EN.htm) that refuses to install the network printer drivers if run from a domain user account, even if it's in the local Administrators group.

The error returned by the installer when running under the domain account in the local Administrators group is that it is not running with administrator privileges.  If I log out and back in as a local user in the Administrators group, then the installer works.

**The Question**:

Is there an issue in the way the program checks for admin privileges?  Are there any key differences in privileges for domain users in the Administrators group vs. local users in the Administrators group?

I have taken process monitor logs of both the failed install and the successful install.  Normally I would think that the process would use CheckTokenMembership to see if it is in the administrators group.  Is this something that can easily be checked in Process Monitor?

Comment: I don't know if Process Monitor can check it easily but I have had good luck with [API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor) (It is in alpha but it works good, the dev also follows the forms fairly closely, you can get an answer from him within a day or so of posting if you need a custom XML definition file for a API the program does not yet know how to track, all of the windows API's have been in there for a while)

Comment: Just because your the local user profile is contaned within the Administrators doesn't mean you are an Administrator on the domain.  There is a huge difference.  This sounds like a domain configuration problem dealing with configurations.

Comment: I shouldn't need domain admin permissions to make a change to my local computer with local admin rights.  I forwarded this question on to Canon support but have not received a response in months.